# Next 13 router changing methods (push, replace) have caching problems with server side props

Tags: caching, next.js, next.js13

I am having caching problems with Next 13 routers and its caching behavior with my projects and desperately need help!

The problem is that next-router seems to have caching problems (it uses stale data, not refreshed one ) when it is switching between routes.

In detail, I have four routes, which use `getServerSideProps` to load its initial data about user's information and their layout preferences.

`getServerSideProps` functions deliver these initial payloads to `page.tsx` and seems to working fine with router changing methods until I build the project for deploying to Vercel.

However since then, router switching methods of Next (router.push, replace, Link) seems to use stale caching data.

I found that when I change some information and it just works fine with server and DB.

Then I switch routes with routing methods, the `page.tsx` and `_app.tsx` get always stale data even though `getServerSideProps` is fetching fresh data.

It seems that it is working fine when the first time page load (before caching) or refresh the page.

Is there a way to stop using cached data when route changes or synchronize cached data to refresh data?

next config

```js
/**
 * Run `build` or `dev` with `SKIP_ENV_VALIDATION` to skip env validation.
 * This is especially useful for Docker builds.
 */
import withPWA from "next-pwa";
!process.env.SKIP_ENV_VALIDATION && (await import("./src/env.mjs"));

/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
const config = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  headers: async () => [
    {
      source: "/myapp/:route",
      headers: [
        {
          key: "Cache-Control",
          value: "no-store",
        },
        {
          key: "x-middleware-cache",
          value: "no-cache",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    return config;
  },

  /**
   * If you have the "experimental: { appDir: true }" setting enabled, then you
   * must comment the below `i18n` config out.
   *
   * @see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41980
   */
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
};
export default withPWA({
  dest: "public",
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
})(config);
```

example of getServerSideProps

```js
export const getServerSideProps = withSession<{
  props: {
    data: UserDataState;
  };
}>(async (session, ctx) => {
  ctx.res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  ctx.res.setHeader("x-middleware-cache", "no-cache");

  const helpers = createServerSideHelpers({
    router: appRouter,
    ctx: createInnerTRPCContext({ session }),
    transformer: superjson,
  });
  const userData = await helpers.user.getUserData.fetch();

  return {
    props: userData,
  };
});
```

```js
function withSession<T>(
  getServerSideProps: (
    session: Session,
    ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext
  ) => Promise<T>
) {
  return async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const session = await getServerAuthSession(context);
    if (!session)
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: "/signin",
          permanent: false,
        },
      };

    return await getServerSideProps(session, context);
  };
}
```

Project setup : T3(Next-13, Trpc, Prisma, Next-Auth)

Comment: Did You Solve The Problem?